# Binding with multiple view models

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a viewmodel for a usercontrol that is defined in a data template for the viewmodel. I would like to bind the 'GridViewData' property of the usercontrol to the 'Data' property of the viewmodel.

I am still new to WPF and terrible at bindings, so please be kind :p

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ReportUtility.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:lite="clr-namespace:ReportUtility.Controls.LiteGrid"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ReportUtility.ViewModels"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<!--This is the view model I want to bind to variable name is Grid: hosted in the content control below-->
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LiteGridViewModel}">
        <lite:LiteGrid GridViewData="{Binding ??}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="TestButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Command="{Binding ExecuteQueryCommand}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=SqlCommandText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Grid}" Grid.Row="2" Background="Red"/>

    <Border Background="Aqua" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="3" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: if Data is a property in your viewmodel, will GridViewData="{Binding Data}" not work?

Comment: I also have a view model that is the datacontext for the main window...will it not try to bind to that instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would bind to `Data`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LiteGridViewModel}">
    <lite:LiteGrid GridViewData="{Binding Data}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

It would even be better to do this binding in the `LiteGrid` UserControl instead of relying on the XAML that uses the control to set the value.

```
<UserControl GridViewData="{Binding Data}">
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Your bindings always reference the current object's `DataContext`. Since your `DataTemplate` is for type `LiteGridViewModel`, the `DataContext` within that `DataTemplate` is always going to be of type `LiteGridViewModel`.

For example, if you have a class like

```
public class MyClassA
{
    MyClassB ClassB {get; set;}
}

public class MyClassB 
{
    MyClassC ClassC {get; set;}
}
```

And a ViewModel property of `MyClassA ClassA` (meaning you can reference `ClassA.ClassB.ClassC`), you could do something like

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ClassA}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ClassB}"> <!-- DataContext is MyClassA -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ClassC}"> <!-- DataContext is MyClassB -->
            <!-- DataContext is MyClassC -->
        </ContentControl>
    </ContentControl>
</ContentControl>
```